# ActiveMQ Artemis audit log filter printed properties

Tags: activemq-artemis

I've activates the audit log as explained in the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html).

Since I have some verbose properties I was wondering if there's a way to filter only selected properties when printing to the audit log.

I've looked at the source code and it seems to use the [toString](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/4c0ed678979ed970927b27dae273825ea5359091/artemis-core-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/message/impl/CoreMessage.java#L1272) method of the CoreMessage and don't seem possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to filter particular message properties out of ActiveMQ Artemis' audit logs.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to use Log4j2 Pattern Layout replace.